# How to distribute leads from system evenly to two parties throughout day?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a system which receives leads (they are piped in via email) and then reformats the leads (capitalises postcodes etc), logs the data in the database and then emails out the lead to a third party.

Now I have another third party coming on board and they want to take leads. I wish to code the system so that it distributes the leads evenly between x (in this case 2) parties throughout the day. One of the parties wants 10 leads per day and the other will have the remainder. I do not want to simply give the first 10 leads to person A and then the rest to the other person. I need to distribute the leads evenly throughout the day. The quality of the leads varies and the time of the day is a factor in determining that quality, hence the desire to distribute evenly throughout day.

I'm trying to think of an algorithm which can help determine who gets the next lead. Obviously all the 'counts' can be stored in the database and that can be used to check who has received what and how many etc. Just struggling with coming up with a tidy way of coding this?

I'm expecting approx 50-60 leads per day, however this can vary day to day. Also moving forward the average could increase to 80-90. The person that gets 10 initially will take more eventually and the balance of proportions between person A & B will shift. I will have a setting in the system for recording how many person A wants. Person B will always get the overflow (whilst an overflow exists).

Can anyone help with this? I code in php.

Comment: The query above has been settled by Halfer (thanks). I also have another issue related to this system. The leads that come in arent all the same. They can be defined in two groups; X and Y. X leads are paid for and Y leads are free. I need to assign the correct proportion of Y leads in relation to the distributed X leads. Issue is that I dont know what the ratio of X:Y will be day to day. It tends to average out at 60:40 (X:Y). I was thinking of taking the previous 7 day average ratio and applying it to todays leads but the actual how of that is quite complex. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll benefit by building the initial system first, and getting the data into a database; that will help you clarify what your data structures look like. It seems the second issue is a similar case to the first issue - just maintain running averages over a suitable time period (week, month, quarter etc) which can be done in your database. If you need to give out free/paid leads to different recipients in the same ratio, you can then use the round-robin method to decide who to award each one to in the same way.

Comment: Same as before, if your ratios are incorrect one day they will correct themselves the next day, as you tweak your ratios to hit targets (A vs B and X vs Y).

Comment: Thanks again. I think maybe im over thinking the second issue. I was thinking about the previous 7 day ratios for each recipient as compared to the overall 7 day ratio of X:Y and then looking at who deserves the next free lead based on the results (I.e. who is under the overall ratio or who has a lower ratio). I suppose I could just do it on average sums from previous 7 days. I just want the number of free leads to be directly proportional to the number of paid leads, based on how many leads each user has. So if person A has 10 leads and the ratio is 60:40 then person A would get 6 free leads.

Comment: Other issue with above is that if today's ratio was different, person B would then get proportionality more than person A. I guess that would be 'ironed' out the following days or would naturally be ironed out by using the running previous 7 day average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to just allocate the first 10 to A, and then the remainder to B, then you'll need to know what your expected lead count is per day. Let us imagine that you get 15 leads per day on average; then you could send two to A, and then 1 to B, on a round-robin basis.

If you get closer to the end of the day, and A only has 8 leads (i.e. your lead count is likely to be lower for the day) you could send any new leads to A regardless of whose turn it is. Or, maybe you could arrange it so that if A ends up with 9 at the end of day 1, then you'll tweak the algorithm the next day to give them 11 at the end of day 2.

Obviously we cannot know enough about your system to give you a definitive algorithm, but that should give you some food for thought. The critical questions are: whether the 10 leads are the bulk of your leads for the day, or just a small fraction; and whether it would be acceptable to deliver *an average* of 10 leads/day to party A.

Comment: Thank you. I'll edit the question above to answer your points but essentially 10 would be the smaller amount. I expect 50-60 per day but it can vary up and down and could increase dramatically moving forward.

Comment: Sorry also delivering an average per day would be fine. I understand this could happen because the lead flow could just stop early evening for example unexpectedly and person A may not have been given all their leads. This can be sorted out the following day. But ideally it'll be accurate on a daily basis.

Comment: I think an average per day would be a better way to do it. I am guessing that, as time goes on, it will get easier and easier to determine how many leads will arrive per day - even if it varies according to the time of year, and even if you start doing more business right across the year. From one day to the next the averages are likely to be consistent, and if party A doesn't have their requirement satisfied on one day, you can increase their allocation ratio by a small fraction until their daily average >10, and then start bringing it down again until it is <10, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help halfer. The thing is I don't want to have to intervene on a daily basis. I'm looking to code something which can handle the job without me manually fiddling. I guess I can code the adjusting into the system by checking the running average for the month (or whatever). The more i think about it, it does seem very difficult to code what I want without knowing the exact numbers.

Comment: "The thing is I don't want to have to intervene on a daily basis". You read something into my comment that wasn't there; I believe the average calculations could be automated.

Comment: I guessed you meant that after thinking about it afterwards. Thanks for your help. I also have another issue related to this problem which Ive added as a comment. If you have ideas there Id appreciate hearing them.